# Recommended method to connect sections of multi-piece crankshaft

Tags: machine-design

I have prepared a crankshaft for a custom industrial machine - I am using an electric motor to turn the crankshaft. The crankshaft has multiple sections in order to accommodate some ball bearings. I am constructing the crankshaft from sections of 2 inch shaft and 1/2 inch thick steel plate:
[image: crankshaft]

I need to find a method of attaching the 2 inch shaft sections to the plate that will be able to keep the crankshaft sections from rotating relative to each other - I imagine using a single bolt will not work. The machine will be under 600ft-lbs of torque. This is the current idea I have, though the bolts are too close to each other and too close to the edges of the metal rod per the regulations I looked up - though I think these regulations are for civil engineering/construction. The bolts are not under excessive torque per preliminary calculations (I imagine they will fail in shear)

[image: Bolt Pattern]

For the most part regulations mention - the minimum spacing distance is three times the diameter of the screw, and the minimum edge distance is 1.5 times the diameter of the screws. Here the distance to the edge is slightly less than one screw diameter. Also the spacing between the bolts does not seem compliant. I am not concerned with any regulations per se- this is prototype not on the market in any way.

[image: Bolt dimensions]

Comment: Look at 12 point bolt head geometry. Pretty nice torque transfer on those surfaces.

Comment: bolts that fasten two pieces together typically do not experience shear - shear forces are held by friction of the joined surfaces

Comment: Design a pipe-socket joint with interference fit and heat/cool to get them to fit. Vibration is the challenge.